# why can i not add string in a structure

Tags: c++, string, struct

I was trying to define structure having an int and string type members.

```
typedef struct emp{
    int sno;
    string name;
}
```

When I allocated space using `malloc` and modified the name variable, it gives `Segmentation Fault`.  
  I searched on stackoverflow and found solution to use `char*` instead of `string` type. Is it because `char*` has a fixed size (pointer size)?
Also how does `sizeof` treats a string variable since its length is not known before allocation?

Comment: What is `string`? Are you sure that it is C and not C++?

Comment: I think you must be confusing with C syntax in C++.. Use c compiler for c code. This will throw compilation error itself.

Comment: sorry ..its c++ ..compiled using g++ not gcc and no compile error was there..

Comment: If so, then you shouldn't be using malloc() to allocate space for objects. Use new() instead.

Comment: why..what's wrong with malloc..??

Comment: It does not actually create objects, only allocates memory.

Comment: malloc()/free() is the way C allocates and frees memory. new/delete is how C++ does it, and it handles all of the necessary things that have to be done if what you're allocating/freeing is an object (i.e., calling the object's constructor/destructor functions). (BTW, new and delete are not functions; they work the same way as a return statement---no parens necessary.)

Comment: @RobH `new-expression` does more than just allocates memory. You can use `malloc` with C++ object, but you will need to handle all that extra stuff yourself.

Comment: thank you for explanation..@RobH and @Revolver_Ocelot ...I understood..:)

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot That's pretty much what I said in my comment. new/delete allocates/frees memory and does the necessary object stuff, such as calling the constructor/destructor.

Comment: A std::string is a container ... and you do not know how it is implemented, and it might be implemented differently on different systems.  On ubuntu 15.10 (64 bit), g++ 5.2.1, for example,  sizeof(emptyString) reports 32 bytes, which does not change when you add characters.  I infer from this that the characters are stored somewhere else.  Then you can conclude that std::string contains pointers to where the data resides, and thus malloc (and free) won't know how to handle this split of location.